# Idiomatic way to handle multiple function argument types

Tags: rust

I'm fairly new to Rust and I would need some guidance on how to handle multiple types for one argument in Rust. I don't even know if that is possible.

I have a function that does a bunch of computations and whose some instructions may vary based on the type of an argument.

In Python, it would read:

```py
def foo(bar):
   # Do a bunch of computations
   if isinstance(bar, TYPE_A):
       # Do this
   elif isinstance(bar, TYPE_B):
       # Do that
```

I don't even know if that is possible in Rust or even recommended. The function body is quite substantial and it seems cleaner to handle this type-based condition using a `match` statement within the function body rather than having two very similar functions that support two different types.

I'm not looking for generics here. Actually in my case, `Type_A` is a Rust `ndarray` instance and `TYPE_B` would be a custom `struct`.

Comment: I guess you want to use an enum. `enum Foo { A(i32), B(String), ... } ` .. the inner value of the type is the actual payload. With some pattern matching, you can get the right value out of the enum and do whatever you want to do. Under the hood, this is like a typed union in C.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without generics your best bet would be to define an enum containing both variants.

```
enum MyParam {
    TypeA(ndarray),
    TypeB(SomeStruct),
}
```

Body of the function would be something like:

```
fn my_func(param: MyParam) {
    match param {
        TypeA(my_narray) => {
           ...
        },
        TypeB(my_struct) => {
           ...
        },
    }
}
```

And you would call it like

```
my_func(MyParam::TypeA(the_array));
my_func(MyParam::TypeB(the_struct));
```