# How to have this simple function work on more than one type of arguments

Tags: function, rust, arguments

I have this simple function that finds out if a float value is in a range:

```
pub fn between(num: f64, min: i32, max: i32) -> bool {
    if num>min.into() && num<max.into() {return true }
    else {return false; }
}
```

How can I change this function so that it works for both floats and integers, or any type of numbers?

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597831/idiomatic-way-to-handle-multiple-function-argument-types) using `enum` but it basically is writing code twice. Is there any way that I can signal multiple types in function definition header?

Comment: Use generics and find out the appropriate constraints, perhaps you'll need [`num-traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits).

Answer (score 3):

You can make the function *generic* over the integer types, i.e. you add type parameters to the function that can be any type. You then need to add *trait bounds* to tell the compiler what you want to be able to do with these types:

```
pub fn between<T, U>(num: T, min: U, max: U) -> bool
where
    T: PartialOrd,
    U: Into<T>,
{
    min.into() < num && num < max.into()
}
```

The bound `T: PartialOrd` tells the compiler that `T` is partially ordered and supports comparison operators like `<`. The bound `U: Into<T>` tells the compiler that values of type `U` can be converted to type `T` using `.into()`.

Further reading:

- [Chapter on generics in the The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html)

Comment: I was getting error: `the trait Ord is not implemented for {float}` with your original code.

Comment: @mso This is already fixed in the answer. Floating point numbers are not "totally ordered" because of NaN values, so we have to relax the constraints to `PartialOrd` instead of `Ord`.